# What more can I do to secure my service?

Tags: appsec, databases

I run a multiplayer gaming service that provides a server list for clients and servers. At the moment it uses an SQLite database stored locally (*which is insecure in itself*). I am drawing up plans to convert it to either MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server in order to provide redundancy and also the ability to view real-time server statistics online.

Now, knowing that a single database is a disaster waiting to happen (plus it is a *gigantic* attack vector, too) I plan to introduce redundancy by:

- Having two database servers, one for internal and one for web (web will be a slave to internal, but the flow of data will not be bidirectional);
- Web database will be completely cleared and regenerated when data duplication takes place from the internal database;
- Web will not have account information stored on it;
- Non-default ports will be used and the firewall will be restricted to only allow specific hosts to connect;

Am I being over-zealous with my security precautions, or should I be adding more layers of security?

Some statistics that may influence any answers:

- 44.8% of players are Russian;
- The service sees around 50 *billion requests* (admittedly they're small) each month;
- There are around 50 new users each month, with this number steadily increasing (and will see a spike in a couple of months when I start advertising it);
- It runs on AWS EC2 servers (I plan to use AWS RDS for the databases)

Comment: Why MySQL or M$Sql over Aurora?

Comment: @RobertMennell MSSQL for me is easier to use (more experience), and Aurora is something I'm considering.

Comment: If you can use MySQL Aurora is the way to go. Then you can have triggers all over the place.

Comment: @RobertMennell [M$Sql](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2002/07/22/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a more proactive approach as well by doing your own penetration testing against a non-production server setup specifically for this sort of thing.

We use BurpSuite's [scanner](https://portswigger.net/burp/scanner.html) feature to test our own products - it has really helped augment our quest to find vulnerabilities. [ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) is a free alternative I've heard good things about, but have not personally used it. Pay particular attention to any SQL injection issues they identify.